# How to "pythonize" this perl substitution regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, perl

I wrote a short perl code to break a long string of text into cuts of 40 characters or below (by inserting breaklines between them, but without splitting a word in the middle).

```
text=~ s!(.{0,40})\s+!$1\n!g;
```

What would be the python 3 equivalent?
Many thanks.

Solution:

```
answer=re.sub(r'(.{0,40})\s', r'\1\n', my_text+" "
```

I changed a solution recommended below to avoid inserting breaklines into words.

Edit: I have added a space at the end of my text in order to avoid putting the last word in a line of its own if the user does not supply a breakline (or another sort of space) in the end of their text.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included: Use [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill):

```
In [15]: import textwrap

In [16]: print(textwrap.fill('This is a very long string with spaces or maybewithoutspaces', width=40))
This is a very long string with spaces
or maybewithoutspaces

In [17]: print(textwrap.fill('Thisisaverylongstringwithspacesormaybewithoutspaces', width=40))
Thisisaverylongstringwithspacesormaybewi
thoutspaces
```

Note, however that `textwrap.fill` tries to break on a space. A more literal equivalent to your Perl code would be:

```
text = re.sub(r'(.{0,40})', r'\1\n', text)
```

For example,

```
In [18]: import re

In [19]: print(re.sub(r'(.{0,40})', r'\1\n', 'This is a very long string with spaces or maybewithoutspaces'))
This is a very long string with spaces o
r maybewithoutspaces

In [22]: print(re.sub(r'(.{0,40})', r'\1\n', 'Thisisaverylongstringwithspacesormaybewithoutspaces'))
Thisisaverylongstringwithspacesormaybewi
thoutspaces
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `textwrap` module

```
import textwrap
txt = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaafdafsdafdafaddafsfdsf'

print(textwrap.fill(txt, width=40))
```

output

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaafdafsdafdafaddafsfdsf
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use slicing

```
N = 40
s = '-'*(4*N+N//2)

print(*(s[i:i + N] for i in range(0, len(s), N)), sep="\n")
```

or after importing more_itertools:

```
from more_itertools import sliced
print(*sliced(s, 40), sep="\n")
```

---

EDIT: Quick comparison

```
N = 40
s = '-'*(8000000*40+40//2)


@timeit
def slicer1(s):
    return "\n".join(s[i:i + N] for i in range(0, len(s), N))

@timeit
def slicer2(s):
    return "\n".join(sliced(s, N))

@timeit
def slicer3(s):
    return re.sub(r'(.{0,'+str(N)+'})', r'\1\n', s)


slicer1(s)
slicer2(s)
slicer3(s)
```

Method 2 should be fast enough and is the simplest one:

```
Function slicer1(s), took: 1.9553 seconds.
Function slicer2(s), took: 2.9460 seconds.
Function slicer3(s), took: 12.6048 seconds.
```

Comment: Unlike OPs regex that at least tries to break at spaces between words, your solution blindly splits lines at every 40th character, note the `\s+` in the original regex. Doing that without regexes is much more difficult.

Comment: The "but without splitting a word in the middle" was added in the question after posting my answer. Before that it was unclear if it is a desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I edited the original question to clarify this, but the \s+ was present in the perl code from the start.

Comment: Yes, it was present. So either the code was not matching the description or the description of requirements was not matching the code. Which was true I had to guess.